# What is the fastest way to check if a line segment contains a point using C++?

Tags: c++, performance, geometry, 2d

I know that there are already many questions about **how** to check whether a line segment contains a point or not, but my question is specifically about which method will most probably be most efficient for a performance-critical application.

Looking around at various SO answers, there seem to be three general approaches:

**Using distance:**

```
float distance(Vector2 a, Vector2 b)
{
    return std::sqrtf(std::powf((a.x - b.x), 2.f) + std::powf((a.y - b.y), 2.f));
}

bool containsPoint(Vector2 lineP, Vector2 lineQ, Vector2 point)
{
    return distance(lineP, point) + distance(point,lineQ) == distance(lineP, lineQ);
}
```

This one I write off quickly since three square root operations doesn't exactly scream fast.

**Calculating the slope of the line segment and then checking if the point is within the bounds:**

```
bool containsPoint(Vector2 lineP, Vector2 lineQ, Vector2 point)
{
    float slope = (lineP.y - lineQ.y) / (lineP.x - lineQ.x);
    float c = lineP.y - lineP.x * slope;
    
    float minX = std::min(lineP.x, lineQ.x);
    float maxX = (minX == lineP.x) ? lineQ.x : lineP.x;
    
    return point.x * slope + c == point.y && point.x >= minX && point.x <= maxX;  
}
```

This is the first approach that I came up with when writing such a function but I am unsure if it is the most efficient in terms of performance.

**Using cross product and dot product:**

```
bool containsPoint(Vector2 lineP, Vector2 lineQ, Vector2 point)
{
    float crossproduct = (point.y - lineP.y) * (lineQ.x - lineP.x) - (point.x - lineP.x) * (lineQ.y - lineP.y)

    if (fabs(crossproduct) > std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon())
    {
        return false;
    }
    float dotproduct = (point.x - lineP.x) * (lineQ.x - lineP.x) + (point.y - lineP.y)*(lineQ.y - lineP.y)
    if (dotproduct < 0.f)
    {
        return false;
    }

    float squaredlengthba = (lineQ.x - lineP.x)*(lineQ.x - lineP.x) + (lineQ.y - lineP.y)*(lineQ.y - lineP.y)
    if (dotproduct > squaredlengthba)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

This one seems longer than the line slope solution but is different in that it doesn't use division, and I've been told that division is 10 times slower than multiplication. So maybe this is the superior solution?

Or is there another, faster way?

Comment: You should profile your code instead of guessing what may be fast, slow, or in-between.

Comment: What performance constraints do you have? It's worth noting that with floating point you'll never get an exact match, but you can test if it is below some minimal distance to the line that's considered "close enough". There are several common algorithms for finding the "distance of a point to a line", the performance of which often depends on what other constraints you have, like do you compare a lot of lines to a much smaller number of points, or vice-versa.

Comment: I suspect that the "distance" solution could be simplified to "squared distance" and that it would need neither `sqrt` nor `pow`. Using `==` when comparing the `float`s looks risky though.

Comment: What is the use pattern of your application? I mean - do you check multiple points against a single line segment? Or one point / multiple segments? Or is it completely random? Can you pre-calculate something and use it repeatedly?

Comment: The last one looks most efficient out of all three, and is also the closest to being "correct". It's written weirdly, as all calculations are using the vectors `point - lineP` and `lineQ - lineP`. It'd be cleaner if you compute those vectors once. The squared-length part looks irrelevant, since the line vector is defined by two points and is therefore not normalized. So, your dot product should always come out between 0 and 1 if the point is on the line. The epsilon test is prone to scaling issues. Adjusting that to test perpendicular square-distance-from-line would be more appropriate.

Comment: What is the application? Collections of line segments are often used to approximate curves - but being "on" a line segment rarely means that you are "on" the curve: the boundary of a circle would be an example. Comparing floats for equality is dangerous: use a relative tolerance (one proportional to the length of the line segment). Which technique is best? I don't know, but I suspect it depends on the underlying application, your platform and the compiler options.

Comment: You can (and probably should) also precede your expensive checks by simply making sure that your test point's coordinates lie between min(a.x, b.x) and max(a.x, b.x) and similarly for y. These bounds might also be worth precomputing for all line segments.

Comment: @lastchance This is beside the question but out of curiosity: Why would line segments be used for approximating the boundary of a circle? Why not simply represent circles as center points and radiuses?

Comment: It was simply an illustration @JensB. "On" the circle would be tested as "at that radius" rather than on any of the pixels, line segments or whatever that approximated it in a discrete rather than continuous world. Any grid in finite-element software uses line segments to approximate continuous curves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should absolutely **profile**, ideally in real conditions, instead of trying to analyze the code to guess which version is fastest. However, there are several other things you should consider here.

#### Using distance

Your `distance` function calls `std::powf` to square a value `X` instead of just doing `X * X`. I'm unsure whether a compiler will optimize this, but it just looks wrong to me anyway.

Your `containsPoint` function calls `distance` three times, which means three square roots as you mention. However, you can easily simplify this to just one square root by finding a solution to the equation `sqrt(a) + sqrt(b) = sqrt(c)`. Solving for `c`, you can find `c = a + b + 2*sqrt(a*b)`

With this, the code becomes:

```
float distanceSquared(Vector2 a, Vector2 b)
{
    auto dx = (a.x - b.x);
    auto dy = (a.y - b.y);
    return dx*dx + dy*dy;
}

bool containsPoint(Vector2 lineP, Vector2 lineQ, Vector2 point)
{
    auto d2PPoint = distanceSquared(lineP, point);
    auto d2QPoint = distanceSquared(lineQ, point);
    auto d2PQ = distanceSquared(lineP, lineQ);
    return d2PQ == d2PPoint + d2QPoint + 2*std::sqrt(d2PPoint*d2QPoint);
}
```

Also, you probably want to use an approximate equality instead of a straight comparison with `==`.

#### Using the slope

This method simply does not work for a vertical line, though you can of course add a special case for it. It introduces a branch, but it's an unlikely one. Also, to check if `x` is between `a` and `b` without knowing whether `a < b` or `a > b`, you can multiply the differences: check if `(x-a)*(x-b) <= 0`. Additionally, you can do without the division by just rescaling things.

The code becomes:

```
bool containsPoint(Vector2 lineP, Vector2 lineQ, Vector2 point)
{
    float dxPQ = lineP.x - lineQ.x;
    if (dxPQ == 0.f) {
        return (point.y - lineP.y) * (point.y - lineQ.y) <= 0.f;
    }

    float dyPQ = lineP.y - lineQ.y;
    float c = lineP.y * dxPQ - lineP.x * dyPQ;
    bool xBetween = ((point.x - lineP.x) * (point.x - lineQ.x) <= 0.f);
    return xBetween && point.x * dyPQ + c * dxPQ == point.y * dxPQ;  
}
```

Again, you probably want to use an approximate equality for the last part.

#### Using cross product and dot product

Using the dot product is a rather strange way of checking whether the point is within bounds. Instead, you can check the x and y coordinates separately:

```
bool containsPoint(Vector2 lineP, Vector2 lineQ, Vector2 point)
{
    bool xBetween = ((point.x - lineP.x) * (point.x - lineQ.x) <= 0.f);
    bool yBetween = ((point.y - lineP.y) * (point.y - lineQ.y) <= 0.f);
    float crossproduct = (point.y - lineP.y) * (lineQ.x - lineP.x) - (point.x - lineP.x) * (lineQ.y - lineP.y);
    return xBetween && yBetween && std::abs(crossproduct) <= std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon();
}
```

For some reason, you used an approximate equality here, but not in the other versions. In this version, you should use an epsilon proportional to the length of the line, since the cross product will be as well. It does introduce a square root, unless you compare the square of the cross product (in which case you can also drop the `std::abs`). Something like this:

```
bool containsPoint(Vector2 lineP, Vector2 lineQ, Vector2 point)
{
    bool xBetween = ((point.x - lineP.x) * (point.x - lineQ.x) <= 0.f);
    bool yBetween = ((point.y - lineP.y) * (point.y - lineQ.y) <= 0.f);
    if (!xBetween || !yBetween) { // early return or can be moved to the end
        return false;
    }
    float dxPQ = lineQ.x - lineP.x;
    float dyPQ = lineQ.y - lineP.y;
    float lineLengthSquared = dxPQ*dxPQ + dyPQ*dyPQ;
    float crossproduct = (point.y - lineP.y) * dxPQ - (point.x - lineP.x) * dyPQ;
    float tolerance = std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon();
    return crossproduct * crossproduct <= lineLengthSquared * tolerance * tolerance;
}
```

This version looks to me like the most correct and the most understandable (maybe put a few comments here and there). I would not be surprised if it's also the most performant, with or without the branch.

Comment: Why should one not use `std::powf` here? Why would such a function call be potentially detrimental to performance?

Comment: To clarify: I'm referring to the first way using distance, and your note about not using std::powf

Comment: And one more question: Indeed I forgot to include proper epsilon comparison for the floats in the first and second examples. But in your final example, why do you square the epsilon in the return statement? Don't quite understand the logic behind that

Comment: In principle, using `std::pow` means calling a function that does complex things to raise the first argument to the power of the second argument. In practice, the compiler will recognize a call like `std::pow(x, 2)` and transform it into `x*x`. However, that's no guarantee, and even if it were, I find `x*x` easier to read for "x squared" than `std::pow(x, 2)`.

Comment: The epsilon is squared because the line length is squared. Same for the crossproduct. If you don't square it, you would need `std::sqrt(lineLengthSquared)` to make the math correct. And in any case, `std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon()` is probably not the value you want to use. That's why I named the variable "tolerance" instead. Approximate equality is hard. It isn't transitive and it always depends on the type of values (not just variable type) being compared and on the context in which they are being compared.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for the help. If not `std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon()`, what should one use? I've been told that a decent enough epsilon can be made using `std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon()` multiplied by 2 and multiplied by the highest value involved in the particular calculation, if that makes sense. But maybe that's not the case?

Comment: That's for you to decide. In my code, `tolerance` is the maximum distance that a point can be from the line and still be considered "on the line". It's an absolute value, so with a longer line, the relative distance will be smaller. Again, approximate equality always depends on the context. If you want to work with a relative distance instead, like "1% of the line length", then you need something slightly different.

Comment: What do you reckon is the most common practice is in 2D calculation for game development, an absolute distance or a relative one?

Comment: I reckon the most common practice is the laziest one. "2D calculation for game development" is way too broad to give a correct answer. I can't even think off the top of my head of a situation in a game where you want to know if a point lies on a line segment. Collisions will use a different method. UI (where the point is the mouse position) will use a different method. Pathing will use a different method. Without know exactly what problem you are trying to solve, nobody can tell you what option is best for you.

Comment: Fair enough, but for `epsilon` or `tolerance` values in general when it comes to collision, is either relative or absolute ones used more than the other? Or is one almost always more desirable than the other? Or does it simply vary and it's impossible to give a general answer?

Comment: For the third time: the correct choice depends on the context. That literally means there is no general answer. If you don't know which option to choose, just try one. If it works for you, great! Moreover, when I said "collisions will use a different method", I meant that you don't detect collisions by checking if a point lies on a line segment. You just check on which side of the line it is (given by a simple dot product). And you usually do that for multiple points.

Comment: Thanks for the help! A question about the use of `std::powf`: Since you say that squaring yourself with `*`could potentially be more efficient (and easier to read) than using `std::powf`, can one implement their own inline square function that simply squares two arguments, one that isn't implemented to deal with any exponent? Or could that potentially also be less efficient? I ask because "manually" squaring with `*` can get tedious if you're squaring long variable names or similar.

Comment: Like `float squared(float x) { return x*x; }`? Of course you can.

Answer (score 0):

The question is interesting from both mathematical and programming point of view. You can think of this scenario as a right angle triangle problem:

[image]

You can then convert the division into multiplication and gain computational speed.

Also, if the program has to test a significantly large amount of 2D points, where most of the points may not fall on the line, a discarding policy can be helpful. In this case, you can check for the individual dimensional distances abs(px-ax) + abs(px-bx) > abs(ax-bx) || abs(py-ay) + abs(py-by) > abs(ay-by) -> then return false otherwise run the above method. The scenario can look like this:

[image]

The check will work to discard the point Q but P & R still needs to be tested.

The code can look like this:

```
bool containsPoint(Vector2 lineP, Vector2 lineQ, Vector2 point)
{
    if((abs(point.x - lineP.x) + abs(point.x - lineQ.x)) > abs(lineP.x - lineQ.x) || (abs(point.y - lineP.y) + abs(point.y - lineQ.y)) > abs(lineP.y - lineQ.y))
        return false;
    
    float x = abs(lineP.x - lineQ.x);
    float y = abs(lineP.y - lineQ.y);
    float x1 = abs(lineP.x - point.x);
    float y1 = abs(lineP.y - point.y);

    return if x*y1 == x1*y;  
}
```

But if you want to further optimise it, you can avoid the variable declarations and assignments:

```
bool containsPoint(Vector2 lineP, Vector2 lineQ, Vector2 point)
{
    if((abs(point.x - lineP.x) + abs(point.x - lineQ.x)) > abs(lineP.x - lineQ.x) || (abs(point.y - lineP.y) + abs(point.y - lineQ.y)) > abs(lineP.y - lineQ.y))
        return false;

    return if abs(lineP.x - lineQ.x)*abs(lineP.y - point.y) == abs(lineP.x - point.x)*abs(lineP.y - lineQ.y);  
}
```

Comment: Avoiding variable declarations and assignments are not optimisations (unless the variables or results of assignments are unused). Most modern compilers can elide (remove from existence) unused variables or calculations with results that are not subsequently used - and do that more effectively than a human can.   Use of separate variables also often helps a human *better understand* what the code is doing, which (among other things) increases the chances of getting the code working *correctly*, and means that compiler optimisations are less likely to make it malfunction.

Comment: It's true that the use of separate variables helps readability, debugging, and variable-watch. However, when it comes to the assembly level, each variable declaration and assignment adds 2 instructions. Perhaps with modern compilers, declaration instruction can be done only once  (not claiming this), but the assignment operation "MOV AX, NUM" still has to be performed.
For the best (coding) practices, you are absolutely right @Peter.

Comment: @medialness You don't understand how modern compilers work. They can absolutely remove any variable declaration (and assignment) if it does not change the result of the program.

Comment: Interesting, can you please add some references to it @Nelfeal

Comment: @medialness https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if.

Comment: @Nelfeal - The reference to "removing any variable declaration (and assignment)" appears incongruous within the aforementioned context, I'm genuinely curious as it will help to shape my research project.

Comment: @medialness The context is that since `x*y1 == x1*y` has the same observable behavior as `abs(lineP.x - lineQ.x)*abs(lineP.y - point.y) == abs(lineP.x - point.x)*abs(lineP.y - lineQ.y)`, the compiler can compile the program as if you had written the latter, even if you wrote the former.  The trick is that it has to be able to prove that the observable behavior is the same.  That's fairly trivial to do in this case, but can be hard in some cases (i.e. if you form a pointer or reference to any of the variables that may "escape" the currant context).

Comment: @medialness The key part is "if it does not change the result of the program", which is obviously the case in your code. You cannot say that a variable declaration in C++ (or C) adds an instruction in the resulting assembly. That simply makes no sense. C++ code does not directly translate to assembly code: a compiler stands in between, and a good (modern) compiler will use the as-if rule as much as it can in order to perform optimizations. Case in point, GCC produces the exact same assembly for both versions of your code (after some fixes): https://godbolt.org/z/8EWsdhs6j.

Comment: @medialness -- This isn't the 1990's or earlier any more.  The practice of a programmer trying to beat the compiler's optimizer by doing "tricks" is going to be a losing game for the programmer.

Comment: @Nelfeal — the compiler is allowed to do floating-point calculations at higher precision than the types involved, but when the result of a calculation is assigned to a variable the result must be converted to the appropriate type. So storing those values requires a step that isn’t required if they aren’t stored. You’re right, though, that whether the values are actually stored cannot be detected by a conforming program. Types having constructors or destructors with side effects are a different matter…

Answer (score 0):

I would go a different way with this, so I thought I'd add my two penneth. I wrote the following functions to calculate the minimum distance from a point to a straight line between A and B. Then the calling program can decide if that number is small enough for the point to be considered to be on the line or not. Using a boolean with floating point values seems prone to false negatives to me. I would do it this way. It's in c because I don't use c++, but it should be easy to translate.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

// gcc pointdistfromline.c -o pointdistfromline.bin -O3 -march=native --fast-math -lm -Wall

void nearestpointonline2D(float lineAx, float lineAy, float lineBx, float lineBy, float pointPx, float pointPy, float *lineQx, float *lineQy) {
  float PxminusAx = pointPx - lineAx;
  float PyminusAy = pointPy - lineAy;
  float BxminusAx = lineBx - lineAx;
  float ByminusAy = lineBy - lineAy;
  float lenABsqrd = BxminusAx*BxminusAx + ByminusAy*ByminusAy;
  // Q = A + lambda*(B - A)
  float lambda = (PxminusAx*BxminusAx + PyminusAy*ByminusAy) / lenABsqrd;
  if (lambda < 0.0f) lambda = 0.0f;
  if (lambda > 1.0f) lambda = 1.0f;
  *lineQx = lineAx + lambda*BxminusAx;
  *lineQy = lineAy + lambda*ByminusAy;
}

float pointdistfromline2D(float lineAx, float lineAy, float lineBx, float lineBy, float pointPx, float pointPy) {
  // Returns minimum distance from P to straight line between A and B.
  float pointQx;
  float pointQy;
  nearestpointonline2D(lineAx, lineAy, lineBx, lineBy, pointPx, pointPy, &pointQx, &pointQy);
  float PxminusQx = pointPx - pointQx;
  float PyminusQy = pointPy - pointQy;  
  return sqrt(PxminusQx*PxminusQx + PyminusQy*PyminusQy);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  float ax, ay, bx, by, px, py;
  ax = atof(argv[1]);
  ay = atof(argv[2]);
  bx = atof(argv[3]);
  by = atof(argv[4]);
  px = atof(argv[5]);
  py = atof(argv[6]);
  printf("Minimum distance = %f\n", pointdistfromline2D(ax, ay, bx, by, px, py));
}
```