MySQL Distance from Point inside polygon to polygon boundary
I have a MySQL point inside a MySQL polygon.  I need to know how close this point is to the boundary of the polygon. According to other related posts ST_DISTANCE only works with points outside of a polygon.
I'd like to do this in a MySQL (8.0+) query.  But if that's not possible, I can write Java code to it.  I just need help on the algorithm.
I've seen this problem asked several times.  But I haven't found any MySQL or Java answer or a response that definitively says it can't be done.

My answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77276537/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-check-if-a-line-segment-contains-a-point-using-c can give the distance of a point from a line segment. You would have to repeat for each segment and take the minimum. There's the winding number algorithm to check the point is inside a polygon.

That should work.  All of the other point to line algorithms I've found assume an infinite line.  Does your algorithm work with a line that only stretches between two points?

"Does your algorithm work with a line that only stretches between two points?" As opposed to what? Like i said before, if you have multiple line segments, in your case, the edges of your polygon, you could calculate the minimum distance to each edge and then take their minimum.

You can use this sql code

WITH RECURSIVE
-- Step 1: Extract the exterior ring as a linestring
exterior_ring as (
    SELECT ST_AsText(ST_ExteriorRing(polygon_geom)) as ring
    FROM geometries
    WHERE ST_Contains(polygon_geom, point_geom)
),
-- Step 2: Convert the linestring to individual segments
linestring_points as (
    SELECT 
        ST_PointN(ST_GeomFromText(ring), n) AS point
    FROM exterior_ring,
    (
SELECT 1 AS n 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 3 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 4 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 5 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 6 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 7 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 8 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 9 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 10) as numbers
    WHERE n <= ST_NumPoints(ST_GeomFromText(ring))
),
segments AS (
    SELECT
        p1.point AS start_point,
        LEAD(p1.point) OVER (ORDER BY p1.point) as end_point
    FROM linestring_points as p1
),
-- Step 3: Calculate the distance from the point to each segment
distances AS (
    SELECT 
        ST_Distance(point_geom, ST_MakeLine(start_point, end_point)) AS distance
    FROM segments, geometries
    WHERE end_point IS NOT NULL
)
-- Step 4: Select the minimum distance
SELECT MIN(distance) as distance_to_boundary
FROM distances;


Reminder: Answers generated by artificial intelligence tools are not allowed on Stack Overflow. Learn more

thank you for your attention, I used it to explain it better, but I removed that part.

Note that these rules also apply to code.
